# Stopping an audio element by ID

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Thanks for checking out my question. I'm running into a stumbling block stopping an audio element and I'm hoping to get some help. I'm creating audio elements dynamically with arguments, like this.

```
var audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.setAttribute('id', params[0]);
```

This works fine, params[0] is a user argument. I can alert audio.id and I get 'backgroundmusic' for example. And audio.play works. The problem comes when I try to stop it.

```
var audio = document.getElementById(params[0]);
audio.pause();
```

I thought this would work, but it returns null every time. I'm a total javascript rookie and Im sure this is a rookie mistake, but what am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the audio element, append it to some element in the dom.

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://home.tiscali.nl/~jvanderw/malaysia02/sounds/greatargus.mp3');
    audioElement.setAttribute('id', "user_id");
    audioElement.load()
$("#audio_div").append(audioElement);
```

I created a fiddle, check this http://jsfiddle.net/QG68M/

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I wasn't even registering that there actually was no element to find.

Answer (score 0):

I had observed that you did not attached the audio object to the DOM/Document. This causes document.getElementByID to fail in finding the element. the easiest way to stop the audio file from playing is to keep a reference to the audio object that you created.

```
var audioControl;

function CreateAudioElement(params)
{
    audioControl = document.createElement("audio");
    audioControl.setAttribute('id', params[0]);
}

function StopAudioElement()
{
  audioControl.pause();
 }
```

Comment: This is also a great solution. Thanks very much.

Comment: @user3152117 please dont forget to upvote and mark this as an answer. :) tnx

Comment: I would upvote if I had the reputation myself. I literally just started javascript this month.